# How to use init.lua instead of init.vim

Tags: lua, neovim

My friend wrote a config for me in init.lua but as I am new , I only know how to configure init.vim with vim-plug .. If I got init.lua then how Do i install the package using neovim ?

Answer (score 5):

What you could do, is source your vim script file with your vim-plug block from within init.lua using `vim.cmd` (see: [neovim docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#lua-vim)).

To source your vim-plug file from your nvim config location, which in my case on macOS and Debian is `$HOME/.config/nvim/` you could place the following in your init.lua:

```
vim.cmd [[source ~/.config/nvim/vimplugconfig.vim]]
```

And then `~/.config/nvim/vimplugconfig.vim` could look like:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'numirias/semshi', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }

call plug#end()
```

If you are using vim-plug for both vim and neovim, here's an example plugin that was already installed with vim-plug in vim, so that you don't have to install it twice. Following the above example here's what you'd have in your `~/.config/nvim/vimplugconfig.vim`:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'junegunn/limelight.vim', {'dir': '~/.vim/plugged/limelight.vim'}

Plug 'numirias/semshi', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }

call plug#end()
```

Just make sure you don't put the neovim plugin specific lines (e.g. semshi) in your `.vimrc`, because then vim-plug will try to manage it, and it may fail.

Finally, [vim-plug README.md](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/README.md#neovim) does mention how to install it when it comes to neovim either with curl or flatpak (on Unix/Linux), but they don't actually mention how to do anything in lua specifically when calling vim-plug, so I've personally stuck with the above method while using vim-plug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Vim Plug works with lua config, but you can use [packer](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim).

Comment: They have the instructions on the README.md

Answer (score 0):

You could continue using init.vim - if you are more used to that - and add the lua part in the init.vim file
by putting the lua code inside a
**:lua-heredoc block:** search for lua-heredoc [in the documentation for neovim](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua-guide.html)
Here is an example from my init.vim where the lua code:

```
  require("toggleterm").setup{
      open_mapping = [[<c-\>]]
```

is put inside the init.vim

```
" other init.vim config
call plug#begin('~/AppData/Local/nvim/plugged')
" other plugins
Plug 'rust-lang/rust.vim'
Plug 'github/copilot.vim'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'akinsho/toggleterm.nvim', {'tag' : '*'}
call plug#end()
lua << EOF
require("toggleterm").setup{
  open_mapping = [[<c-\>]]
}
EOF
```